# Figure on the same page as appendix section in landscape mode

Tags: floats, appendices, landscape

I have a bunch of figures placed at the end of my document in a landscape mode. I would like to put all these figures under an appendix section called "Figures". I used the following code to accomplish this. This code produces a blank page with the section heading "A Figures" and figures start from the next page. I want the first figure to start from the page with the section heading "A Figures". Could anybody please help? Thanks in advance.

```
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\centering

\section{Figures}

 \begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{Jun_99_Sep00_symmetric}
    \caption{5 Historical periods}
    \label{fig:6sym99rec}
    \end{figure} 
 \end{landscape}

 \begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{Jun99_Sep00_asymmetric_open_false}
    \caption{2 Historical periods}
    \label{fig:6asym99rec}
    \end{figure} 
 \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`landscape` always starts and ends with a  new page (it executes `\clearpage` at the start and end of the environment), you could instead use `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package or just normal `figure` and just rotate the image with

```
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{...}}
```

Comment: I tried your command \rotatebox and also sidewaysfigure. It did not solve my problem. Figures still start from the page after the appendix page.

Comment: any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution myself. Made some minor changes to my previous code:

```
\begin{landscape} 
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\centering

\section{Figures}


 \begin{figure}[H]
   \includegraphics[scale=.4]{Jun_99_Sep00_symmetric}
   \caption{5 Historical periods}
   \label{fig:6sym99rec}
 \end{figure} 

 \begin{figure}[H]
   \includegraphics[scale=.4]{Jun99_Sep00_asymmetric_open_false}
   \caption{2 Historical periods}
   \label{fig:6asym99rec}
 \end{figure} 

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The above code results in figures starting from the same page as the Appendix starts. However, although all the pages before the appendix page are in portrait mode, the rest are in landscape. So the pdf file looks a little strange.